# Convergence of $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \ln(\frac{n^2+1}{n^2})$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

**Question:**

Study the convergence of the following series:
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \ln\left(\frac{n^2+1}{n^2}\right)$$

How can I resolve this problem ? I tried so many different ways, and it is not working !

***EDIT***

Found a way to resolve.

As :

$$\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{\ln\left(1+\frac{1}{n^2}\right)}{\frac{1}{n^2}} = 1$$

because,

$$n \mapsto \infty \Leftrightarrow \frac{1}{n^2} \mapsto 0$$

Then, the two series are convergent, because

$$\sum\frac{1}{n^2}$$

is convergent too.

Comment: It would be great if you explain what have you already tried.

Comment: Do you need to **find** the sum (it happens to be $\ln(\sinh(\pi)/\pi)$, but that's not very elementary), or to determine whether it converges?

Comment: I just want to know if it converges or if it is divergent

Comment: The answer is $\ln\left(\dfrac{\sinh(\pi)}\pi\right)$.

Comment: Next time, please say in your post what your question is.

Answer (score 7):

Note that: $\ln(1+x)\le x$ for all $x>0$.

Hint:

$$\ln \left( {\frac{{{n^2} + 1}}{{{n^2}}}} \right) = \ln \left( {1 + \frac{1}{{{n^2}}}} \right) \leqslant \frac{1}{{{n^2}}}$$
Since $\sum\limits_{n = 1}^\infty  {\frac{1}{{{n^2}}}} $ converges, we conclude $\sum\limits_{n = 1}^\infty  {\ln \left( {\frac{{{n^2} + 1}}{{{n^2}}}} \right)} $ converges, by the comparison test.

Answer (score 4):

Notice that for $[1,\infty)$, $f(x) = \ln \Big(1 + \frac{1}{x^2}\Big)$ is positive, continuous and $f'(x) = -\frac{2}{x^3 + x} < 0$ for $x > 1$. Then

As $$\require{cancel}\begin{align}\int_{1}^{\infty}\ln\Big(1 + \frac{1}{x^2}\Big)dx &= \lim_{t \to \infty}\int_{1}^{t}\ln\Big(1 + \frac{1}{x^2}\Big)dx \\&= \lim_{t \to \infty} x \ln \Big(1 + \frac{1}{x^2}\Big) + 2 \arctan x \Bigg|_1^{t} \\&= \cancel{\lim_{t \to \infty} t \ln \Big(1 + \frac{1}{t^2}\Big)}^{0} + \lim_{t \to \infty} 2 \arctan t - \ln 2 - \cancel{2}\frac{\pi}{\cancel 4^{\color{#f05}2}} \\&= \color{#05f}{\frac{\pi}{2}- \ln 2}\end{align} $$

Therefore the series $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \ln \left(1 + \frac{1}{x^2} \right)$$

converges by the [Integral Test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integral_test_for_convergence).

Answer (score 1):

Comparison test with $\sum_n 1/n^2$, noting that $\ln(1+t) \le t$ for $t > 0$.

Answer (score 0):

$$
\sum_{n} \ln f(n) = \ln \left( \prod_{n} f(n)\right) 
$$

Comment: I do not think that your hint is easily to solve. How to compute $\prod {f\left( n \right) = ?} $

Comment: Could you elaborate more on your hint? I wonder how the change to the multiplicative infinite series makes the solution of the problem more clear?

Comment: you can apply to the product representation of $\sinh$

Answer (score 0):

This was a comment, but then became long hence I add it below as an answer.

As "Autolatry" and "tired" already mentioned:

\begin{align}
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \ln \Big(1+\frac{1}{n^2}\Big) = \ln \left( \prod_{n=1}^{\infty} \Big(1+\frac{1}{n^2}\Big)\right) 
\end{align}
Now recall that 
\begin{align}
\sinh(x)=x\prod_{n=1}^{\infty}  \Big(1+\frac{x^2}{\pi^2n^2}\Big)
\end{align}
therefore 
\begin{align}
\sinh(\pi)=\pi\prod_{n=1}^{\infty}  \Big(1+\frac{1}{n^2}\Big)
\end{align}
implying that 
\begin{align}
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \ln \Big(1+\frac{1}{n^2}\Big) = \ln \left( \frac{\sinh\pi}{\pi}\right) 
\end{align}